# Best way to handle data list of REST web service with foreign key(one to many)

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, redux

I am going to implement the REST base CRUD modal in my my app.I wan to display the list of product data with edit and delete link

### Product

id, title, unit_id, product_type_id, currency_id,price

Q1: what should be json response look like?

There are two formats comes in my mind to place the data in Json as a response of REST Get call

`[
  {
   id:1,
   title:"T-Shirt",
   unit_id:20,
   unit_title: "abc"
   product_type_id:30,
   product_type_title:"xyz"
   currency_id: 10,
   currency_name: "USD"
   min_price:20
 },
 {...}
]`

and the another one is

`[
  {
   id:1,
   title:"T-Shirt",
   unit: {
       id: 20,
       title: "abc"
   },
   product_type: {
       id: 30,
       title: "xyz"
   },
   currency_id: {
       id:10,
       name: "USD"

   },
   min_price:20
 },
 {...}
]`

what is the better and standard way to handle the above scenario?

Furthermore, let suppose I have 10 more properties in product table which will never display on list page. but i needed it when user going to edit the specific item.

Q2: Should I the load all data once at the time of displaying product list and pass the data to edit component.

or

Load only the needed propeties of product table and pass the id to produt edit component and a new REST GET call with id to get the properties of product.

> I am using React + Redux for my front end

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would create additional methods for API consumers to retrieve the values that populate the lists of `currency`, `product_type` and `unit` when editing in a UI.

I wouldn't return more data than necessary for an individual `Product` object.